# sumif with dynamic column and range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I want to using sumifs function in VBA. And result paste in same column as previous data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay...What have you tried? Would a pivot table not do it?  If you can do this manually with formulas, just use the macro recorder to get the code and tweak from there.

Comment: I can't use pivot table to do it. They ask me to use macro to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Twice a SUMIF with Overwrite

- [Workbook
  Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6moyozsz4rohrjb/sumif-with-dynamic-column-and-range-in-vba_55330395.xlsm?dl=0)
  (Dropbox)
- Couldn't find any indication of `SUMIFS`, so I did it as if there is
  twice a `SUMIF`:
  For Columns `A` and `C`, and for Columns `B` and `D`.

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumUnique(UniqueFirstCell As Range, ValueFirstCell As Range)

    Dim rng As Range      ' Unique Last Used Cell
    Dim dict As Object    ' Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant    ' Dictionary Key Counter (For Each Control Variable)
    Dim vntU As Variant   ' Unique Range Array
    Dim vntV As Variant   ' Value Range Array
    Dim vntUT As Variant  ' Unique Array
    Dim vntVT As Variant  ' Value Array
    Dim curV As Variant   ' Current Value
    Dim NorS As Long      ' Source Number of Rows
    Dim NorT As Long      ' Target Number of Rows
    Dim i As Long         ' Source/Target Row Counter

    ' Copy Unique Range to Unique Range Array.
    With UniqueFirstCell
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Columns(.Column) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    vntU = rng

    ' Copy Value Range to Value Range Array.
    With ValueFirstCell
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Columns(.Column) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    vntV = rng

    ' Create Unique Values and SumIf Values in Dictionary.
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    NorS = UBound(vntU)
    For i = 1 To NorS
        curV = vntU(i, 1)
        If curV <> "" Then
            dict(curV) = dict(curV) + vntV(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    NorT = dict.Count

    ' Resize Unique and Value Arrays to Target Number of Rows.
    ReDim vntUT(1 To NorT, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vntVT(1 To NorT, 1 To 1)

    i = 0
    For Each key In dict.keys
        i = i + 1
        ' Write Dictionary Keys to Unique Array.
        vntUT(i, 1) = key
        ' Write Dictionary Values to Value Array.
        vntVT(i, 1) = dict(key)
    Next

    ' Copy Unique Array to Target Unique Range.
    With UniqueFirstCell
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        rng.ClearContents
        Set rng = .Resize(NorT)
    End With
    rng = vntUT

    ' Copy Value Array to Target Value Range.
    With ValueFirstCell
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        rng.ClearContents
        Set rng = .Resize(NorT)
    End With
    rng = vntVT

End Sub

Sub Uni()
    Uni1
    Uni2
End Sub

Sub Uni1()
    Const cUni As String = "A2"
    Const cVal As String = "C2"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        SumUnique .Range(cUni), .Range(cVal)
    End With

End Sub

Sub Uni2()
    Const cUni As String = "B2"
    Const cVal As String = "D2"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        SumUnique .Range(cUni), .Range(cVal)
    End With

End Sub
```

I created two command buttons and put the following code into the sheet module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdRevert_Click()
    [A2:D31] = [J2:M31].Value
End Sub

Private Sub cmdUnique_Click()
    Uni
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SumIfs in VBA through the Application or WorksheetFunction object with VBA style range references. You are only going to want to use it once for each pair of column A and column B values. If you use it once then loop to another row with the same pair of column A and column B values, you cannot use it again without getting false results due to the changes you made the first time.

However, those false results are okay if you are just going to delete them anyways and RemoveDuplicates deletes from the bottom up leaving the top-most column A and column B pairs with the correct totals.

[image]

Comment: @user11246173 Please never post code as pictures. Instead include the code in your question/answer and format it as code block. Also see [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).